# Connection refused when using wiremock

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, wiremock

I have this piece of code in a Junit, where I clearly set the port to 8888

```
when(clientUtils.getLinkUrl(eq(HOSTELS_MICROSERVICE.name()), eq(HOSTELS_MICROSERVICE.name()), anyMap()))
                .thenReturn("http://localhost:8888/HOSTELS/HOSTELSMethods");

stubFor(com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.get("/HOSTELS/HOSTELS_LIST").willReturn(
                aResponse().withStatus(200)
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .withBody(ResourceUtils.getResourceFileAsString ("__files/HOSTELS.json"))));
```

but when I run the test I got this error on this line:

```
stubFor(com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.get("/HOSTELS/HOSTELS_LIST").willReturn(..
```

and the error:

```
wiremock.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## For Java users

Based on the [`WireMock`](http://wiremock.org/docs/configuration/) docs.

There are 3 possibilities to use WireMock in your tests :

1. If you are using Wiremock as JUnit 4 rule to configure the port use :

```
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig;

...

@Rule
public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(wireMockConfig().port(8888));
```

2. If you are using new instance and start it from your Test class (for example `@Before`) :

```
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.options;

...

public class Test {

    WireMockServer wm;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        wm = new WireMockServer(options().port(8888));
        wm.start();
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        wm.stubFor(...);
    }
}
```

3. With static configuration of default instance (not using new instance in your test) :

```
WireMock.configureFor(8888);
```

## For Kotlin users

If you are using kotlin you can add actual wiremock instance to `stubFor` and `verify` calls like `wm.stubFor()` and configure the port like in option 3 of this answer.

Comment: hmm still: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused). unit 5

Comment: hi @ses i recently just figured this out. i am using Kotlin and JUnit 5, but had that `HttpHostConnectException` issue. I resolved it by adding the actual `WireMockServer` instance to my `stubFor` or `verify` methods, i.e. `wireMockServer.stubFor()` or `wireMockServer.verify()`. After doing this, the tests work. Hope it helps.

Comment: For completeness, it's worth mentioning that you might have to also start the server. I went with option 2. with `new WireMockServer()` but forgot to call `wm.start()` and was getting `Connection refused`

Comment: @billydh, you should add your comment as an answer.  It worked for me, and I'm sure a lot of other people too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Posting my previous comment as an answer as it seems to have helped a few people. Thanks @jmrah. :)

For **Kotlin** and **JUnit5**, this can be resolved by adding the actual `WireMockServer` instance to the `stubFor` or `verify` method calls.

```
wireMockServer.stubFor()
```

or

```
wireMockServer.verify()
```

After adding this, the tests should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `WireMockServer` object and assign it to a variable say `wm`, then use this variable with the method like so `wm.stubFor(...)`. If you don't use the `wm` variable, you will get the error `connection refused`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this: @AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0, httpsPort = xxxx)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).