# Connection refused when trying to call Wiremock Stub

Tags: java, spring, gradle, cucumber-jvm, wiremock

I'm trying to integrate Cucumber-JVM with WireMock and I keep getting

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I've tried several tutorials, including the [Official Docs](http://wiremock.org/docs/junit-rule/) from cucumber.io
And also tried these below:

[Introduction to WireMock from Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-wiremock)

[Stuff from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57626072/connection-refused-when-using-wiremock)

[Wiremock Github Issues page](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/20)

My Gradle dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'   
testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:6.2.2'
testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:6.2.2'
testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:spring-web-test-client:4.3.1'
testCompile "com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8:2.27.0"
compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-spring', version: '6.4.0'
```

The basic idea is to Mock a Server Response, so in the future I'll be able to create some integration tests between several microservices.
The idea came from a book while I'm reading
[The Cucumber for Java Book](https://www.amazon.com.br/dp/B00V20IEXM/ref=dp-kindle-redirect?_encoding=UTF8&btkr=1)
If there are better ways to test microservices I'm open to new ideas.

I've a Test Class with my Step Definitions that getting the port info form a propertie file. Like below:

```
@SpringBootTest
@CucumberContextConfiguration
public class ConnectionWithCucumber {

    @Value("${another.server.port}")
    private int PORT;

    @Rule
    private WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(PORT);

    private String messageResult;

    @Given("I want to read a message")
    public void iWantToRead() {
        createMessageStub();
    }

    @When("I send the request")
    public void iSendTheRequest() {
        messageResult = given().get("localhost:8082/message").getBody().asString();
    }

    @Then("I should be able to read the word {string}")
    public void iShouldBeAbleToReadTheWord(String arg0) {
        assertEquals(arg0, messageResult);
    }

    private void createMessageStub() {
        wireMockRule.stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/message"))
                .withHeader("Accept", equalTo("application/json"))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .withBody("message")));
    }
}
```

And I've also created a [repository](https://github.com/JohnneSouza/cucumber-wiremock-integration) with a runnable example.

If you don't find a README file, while looking the repo you can run the project by using:

```
./gradlew cucumber
```

or if you are on Windows:

```
gradle cucumber
```

After I got it working, I refactored the code and left the example on the repository I've linked above, if you are have the same problem check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WireMockRule` depends on the `@Rule` annotation which comes from JUnit 4. It doesn't have any effect when used in Cucumber. Instead consider using `@AutoConfigureWireMock` from `spring-boot-starter-web` to setup wiremock.

```
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    │       └── com
    │           └── example
    │               └── Application.java
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── example
        │           └── CucumberTest.java
        └── resources
            ├── application.yml
            ├── com
            │   └── example
            │       └── hello.feature
            └── junit-platform.properties
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <cucumber.version>6.5.0</cucumber.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR7</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Configuration
    @ConfigurationProperties("com.example")
    public static class HelloConfiguration {

        String helloService;

        public String getHelloService() {
            return helloService;
        }

        public void setHelloService(String helloService) {
            this.helloService = helloService;
        }

    }

    @RestController
    public static class HelloController {

        private final RestTemplate helloService;

        public HelloController(
                RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder,
                HelloConfiguration configuration) {
            this.helloService = restTemplateBuilder
                    .rootUri(configuration.getHelloService())
                    .build();
        }

        @RequestMapping("/local")
        public String local() {
            return "Greetings from Local!";
        }

        @RequestMapping("/remote")
        public String remote() {
            return helloService.getForObject("/", String.class);
        }

    }

}
```

```
package com.example;

import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.AutoConfigureWireMock;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.okJson;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.stubFor;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

@Cucumber
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0)
public class CucumberTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Given("the application says hello")
    public void getLocalHello() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/local").accept(APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(equalTo("Greetings from Local!")));
    }

    @Given("the stub says hello")
    public void getRemoteHello() throws Exception {
        stubFor(WireMock.get("/").willReturn(okJson("Greetings from Stub!")));

        mvc.perform(get("/remote").accept(APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(equalTo("Greetings from Stub!")));
    }

}
```

```
Feature: Hello world

  Scenario: Calling a rest end point
    * the application says hello
    * the stub says hello
```

```
com:
  example:
    hello-service: http://localhost:${wiremock.server.port}
```

Comment: Well, I made a copy from your code and pasted on my project, instead of getting a Connection Refused I'm getting a 404. I even changed the "the stub says hello" to "/remote" instead of "/", but no success.

Comment: Here I'm again. I came back to read line by line of your answer and the problem was on the @AutoConfigureWireMock. I had to do some refactor, but got it working. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect this means there is no service listening on the port please try to print the port in which the service is running and check. I can see u have already checked whether wiremock is running or not please do check the port also

You can add test property like this. that will override the default application.properties

```
    @TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "application.location=http://localhost:8082/app/api/v1/"

})
```

please change the url in the line to

```
 Header header = new Header("Accept","application/json")
 messageResult = given().header(header).port(8082).get("/message").getBody().asString();
```

instead of

```
  messageResult = given().get("localhost:8082/message").getBody().asString();
```

it is working for me

```
@SpringBootTest
@CucumberContextConfiguration
public class ConnectionWithCucumber {

    @Value("${another.server.port}")
    private int PORT;


    @Rule
    private WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(8082);

    private WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(8083);


    private String messageResult;

    @Value("${test.word}")
    private String word;

    @Value("${test.number}")
    private String number;

    @Test
    public void testWord(){
        wireMockServer.start();
        wireMockRule.start();
        wireMockRule.isRunning();
        wireMockServer.isRunning();
        System.out.println(wireMockRule.port());
        assertThat(word).isEqualTo("word");
        assertThat(number).isEqualTo("number");
    }


    @Given("I want to read a message")
    public void iWantToRead() {
        wireMockServer.start();
        wireMockRule.start();
        wireMockRule.isRunning();
        wireMockServer.isRunning();
        System.out.println("wireMockRule port " + wireMockRule.port());
        System.out.println("wireMockServer port " + wireMockServer.port());

        // Start the stub
        createMessageStubServer();
        createMessageStub();

        wireMockServer.getStubMappings();
        wireMockRule.getStubMappings();
    }

    @When("I send the request")
    public void iSendTheRequest() {
        System.out.println("iSendTheRequest" + wireMockRule.isRunning());
        System.out.println("iSendTheRequest" + wireMockServer.isRunning());
        Header header = new Header("Content-Type","application/json");
        messageResult = given().port(8082).and().header("Accept","application/json").and()
                .get("/message").getBody().asString();

        System.out.println(messageResult);

    }

    @Then("I should be able to read the word {string}")
    public void iShouldBeAbleToReadTheWord(String arg0) {
        System.out.println(messageResult);
        System.out.println("arg0"+arg0);
        assertEquals(arg0, messageResult);
    }

    private void createMessageStub() {
        wireMockRule.stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/message"))
                .withHeader("Accept", equalTo("application/json"))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .withBody("Response")));
    }

    private void createMessageStubServer() {
        wireMockServer.stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/message"))
                .withHeader("Accept", equalTo("application/json"))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .withBody("{\"message\":\"1\"}")));
    }
}
```

This is the working code you are using wire mock rule and wire mock server we need not use both as per documenation u can use wiremock rule alone that is enough it will start and stop the server before every test

please refer
http://wiremock.org/docs/getting-started/

Don't use random port because of this test cases might fail in other environments use fixed port as you did with your code

You can either use wiremock rule or spring way of using @AutoConfigureWireMock it will auto inject dependecies so spring will start and stop the mock server instead of junit.

please refer https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/reference/html/project-features.html#features-wiremock for spring wire mock docs

one more thing to note here @Rule is executed before spring so it is not getting the port value since @Rule belongs to junit you have to only hard code the port in @Rule annotation or you can use @AutoConfigureWireMock that is the reason i have hardcoded it

Comment: Ramaman, altough it is not mentioned (yet) on the text, I've already run a debug on the `PORT` variable to check whether is recieving a value or not, and it is.. About overrind the properties, that would create another problem for me, since in the future I'll be using multiple profiles. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I've replace the URL as you said, but still getting the Connection Refused.